# Изменение данных в текстовом поле, от выбранного пункта из списка

Tags: php, css, javascript

В общем суть проблемы такая у меня есть список

<select>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
</select>

и есть поле

<input type="text" value="50$" disabled />

проблема в общем в том что от выбора значения из списка меняется сумма в текстовом поле.

Кто что предложит? =)

Comment: Так проблема в том, что "от выбора в списке меняется значение в текстовом поле" или в том, что "при выборе в списке должно меняться значение в текстовом поле"?

Comment: Необходимо от выбора пункта из списка, менять данные в текстовом поле
Option 1 = 20$
Option 2 = 30$
Option 100500 = 1$

В голову никаких идей не лезет )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="myselect"> <option value="1">Вариант 1</option> <option value="2">Вариант 2</option> </select>
<input type="text" value="50$" id="mytext" disabled />

//Для jquery сами разберетесь
    function $(id){
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

$('myselect').onchange = function(){
  switch($('myselect').value){
    case '1': $('mytext').value=20; break;
    case '2': $('mytext').value=30; break;
    case '3': $('mytext').value=100500; break;
  }
}
```